# Qualcomm Atheros wifi card in monitor mode doesn't find devices on access point

Tags: wifi, kali-linux, airmon-ng, airodump-ng

I recently installed Kali Linux on a spare laptop of mine to test my wifi's security. I checked the supported modes in a console to confirm monitor mode was supported using

```
iw list
```

And it indeed shows Monitor Mode in the list. I tried putting it into monitor mode using two different methods

```
airmon-ng start wlan0
```

And

```
ifconfig wlan0 down
iwconfig wlan0 mode monitor
ifconfig wlan0 up
```

Both ways worked, however whenever I monitor my access point using

```
airodump-ng --bssid MY:BS:ID wlan0mon
```

It shows my access point and the beacons steadily increase. However, I never see any devices show up even though I have plenty connected and have tried to disconnect and manually reconnect to try and force it to show with no luck.

I've made sure that promiscuous mode is also on using

```
ip link set wlan0 promisc on
```

**Questions:**

Am I doing anything wrong?

How can I get devices to actually show up?

Comment: What channel does your access point operate on? By default, `airodump-ng` will cycle through all channels and may not capture everything that is occuring. Try forcing it to your channel with the `-c` flag.

Comment: Channel 1. I've tried setting it using `-channel 1`, but still no luck. Isn't `-c` for frequency?

Comment: Did you `airmon-ng check-kill` before `airmon-ng start wlan0`?

Comment: Someone over at [`aircrack-ng.org`](https://forum.aircrack-ng.org/index.php?topic=1456.0) had a very similar issue. Traced his issue to kernel/drivers.

Comment: Yes, I tried killing all troublesome processes. I'm using the ath5 driver. How can I tell if it's a kernel issue?

Comment: Read the manpage. `-c` or `--channel` sets channel.

Comment: Did you not read the previous comments in this thread @multithr3at3d??